# Possible to call a class function as void?

Tags: c++

```cpp
int Foo(int x) {
}

int Thing::Foo(int x) {
}
```

I'm trying to call a function that expects a `void* InCallback,` when I call it as `Function(Foo)` it does work.

When I try to call it `Function(Thing::Foo)` i get this error:

`argument of type "int (Thing::*)(int x)" is incompatible with parameter of type "void *"`

Is possible somehow to call the class function?

Comment: And what the value of `this` should be in that call? How would you pass that value even theoretically? If `this` is not actually used in `Thing::Foo()`, just make it `static`.

Comment: @Evg sorry, i don't understand your question.

Comment: To call `Thing::Foo()`, you need **two** values: `int` argument and `this` pointer to an object. When a callback `void(int)` is called via a function pointer, only `int` is passed to it. What about `this`? How could it be passed?

Comment: `void* InCallback` is not a function pointer.  The code is already suspect, since function pointers and data pointers are not interchangeable.  Your Thing::Foo is probably not marked `static` in the declaration.  If it were, the code should work (ignoring the data pointer and function pointer conflation).

Comment: You mean that `Function` is declared as `<some type> Function(void *)`?

Comment: @JaMiT yes, i also tried to cast it to void with `Function(  void* (Thing::Foo) )`

Comment: @Eljay when i mark it as static i get this warning on compilation `LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl Thing::Foo(void)" (?Foo@Thing@@SAXXZ)
`

Comment: The situation is basically the same as in [Convert pointer to data member to void *](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15547305/), but I'm hesitant to say a question about a pointer-to-member-function is the same as a question about a pointer-to-data-member.

Comment: Unresolved external is not about compilation, it is about linking. Please show a complete code example that produces this error.