# error: invalid conversion from method to void*

Tags: c++

I am trying to cast a method to a void pointer so that I can use it as a callback method.

```
void* pVoidedFunc = &testmethod;
```

But I get the error:

```
error: invalid conversion from int (*)() to void*
```

The method is:

```
static int testmethod()
{
   return 0;
}
```

How do I cast methods into void pointers?

Comment: Why would you want to cast methods into void pointers?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Casting between void \* and a pointer to member function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307278/casting-between-void-and-a-pointer-to-member-function)

Comment: If this is for a callback method then passing the pointer to the callback method should have the correct signature and not use a generic void*.

Comment: What call are you trying to feed the void * too?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Function pointers casting in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096341/function-pointers-casting-in-c)

Comment: Do you really need a void * for your function pointer?  That's a really poor design.  If the callback is a function that takes no parameters and returns int, it should be declared as such.  Surely the code calling the callback will be casting the void* to a pointer to function taking no arguments and returning int.  Ignoring all the preaching, you'll need a (void *) cast to fix the error.

Comment: Did you have a look at [boost::mem_fn](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/bind/mem_fn.html) or [boost::bind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/bind/bind.html) ?

Comment: @Brian Walker I discovered what I was doing wrong farther in the code about 5 minutes after I asked the question.  You are right, I did not actually need to cast the function to a void pointer.

Comment: @KC-NH The real callback method was much more complicated. This was just a toy example because if this one line function was not going to work, then there was no way the actual method was going to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The language doesn't allow auto conversion of a pointer to a function to a void pointer.

Here's what the C++ Draft Standard (N3337) says about pointer conversion (emphasis mine):

> **4.10 Pointer conversions**
>
> 2 An rvalue of type “pointer to *cv* `T`,” **where `T` is an object type**, can be converted to an rvalue of type “pointer to *cv* `void`.” The result of converting a “pointer to *cv* `T`” to a “pointer to *cv* `void`” points to the start of the storage location where the object of type `T` resides, as if the object is a most derived object (1.8) of type `T` (that is, not a base class subobject).

Functions are not objects. This is stated in:

> **1.8 The C+ + object model**
>
> 1 The constructs in a C + + program create, destroy, refer to, access, and manipulate objects. An *object* is a region of storage. [*Note:* A function is not an object, regardless of whether or not it occupies storage in the way that objects do. ]

Object type is defined as:

> **3.9 Types**
>
> 9 An *object type* is a (possibly cv-qualified) type that is not a function type, not a reference type, and not a void type.