# error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'unsigned int (__thiscall IEngineVGui::* )(unsigned int)' to 'void *'

Tags: c++

So i'm trying to port my friends code that was compiled with GCC to Visual C++.

[image: Picture of what i'm doing and error.]

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please post an actual code and error snippets instead of screenshots

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies here:

```
(void*) &IEngineVGui::GetPanel
```

The type of `&IEngineVGui::GetPanel` is `int (IEngineVGui::*) (int)`, which is a [member function pointer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_member_functions).

You are trying to convert it to a "regular" pointer type, [which is sadly not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307278/casting-between-void-and-a-pointer-to-member-function) because they are handled completely differently. So MSVC is acting correctly by giving you an error. If your code compiled fine on GCC, it was most likely due to a bug and/or a non-standard extension in that particular version.