# What is `R(*pf)(void*, Args...)`, function pointer to a method?

Tags: c++, types, function-pointers, void-pointers, pointer-to-member

I saw this type [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39087141/alternative-to-stdfunction-for-passing-function-as-argument-callbacks-etc/39087660#39087660). I believe he's trying to create a variable `pf` for a member pointer type-erased (that's why there's `void*` there). I then noticed this type signature in similar such classes.

But according to [isocpp](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members#fnptr-vs-memfnptr-types) a non-static member pointer type is defined like this:
`int (Fred::*)(char,float)` (for some class `Fred`)
and a function pointer type is defined like this:
`int (*)(char,float)`

Therefore one would create a member pointer variable `mp` like this:
`int (S::*mp)(int) = nullptr;`

Maybe this `void*` represents `this*` and its another way to define a member pointer variable by defining a function pointer variable? Is this possible?

What is `R(*pf)(void*, Args...)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the declaration of a function pointer. Nothing more than that.

Compatible functions take `void*` and `Args...`, and return `R`.

In the given example, the compatible function that's assigned to the pointer, is a lambda. The `void*` is the type-erased address of some callable `f`, and the `Args...` members are, well, the arguments that'll be passed to that callable. The callable's type is restored by capturing of type aliases inside the lambda  (nice!).

Comment: If `pf` is a function pointer to a Callable as defined [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Callable) then this is a generic way to define any kind of function pointer, member pointer or data member pointer in C++. I found this [page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Callable) for the `INVOKE(f, t1, t2, ..., tN)` operation, which expands the `void*` and the `Args...` arguments accordingly depending on which type of callable it is (function pointer, member pointer, data member pointer). Am I correct?

Comment: @Nikos: Yes, as the answer states, it's a [simple] reimplementation of `std::function` which is a class-based wrapper around callables.

Comment: Ok, this is very interesting stuff. I wasn't sure about this. Thanks for answering.

Comment: @Nikos: Note that, as is also [briefly] explained on the answer, it's more of a wrapper around a pointer-to-a-callable in that it's just a "view". It doesn't copy the callable. It stores a pointer to it. So, unlike with `std::function`, you have to make sure the callable survives long enough for you to make your call. That may or may not be a problem when you use this approach, as some callables don't live very long (although since this approach is incompatible with functors I'm not aware of any obvious examples up-front)

Comment: Yes I understand! I was looking into `std::function`s implementation too. And yes, it's a pointer, all pointers are "views" right? : D

Comment: @Nikos Yep. But the real `std::function` is a bit different and is not really a function pointer kind of thing.

Comment: Yes. Regarding your previous comment.. Are you maybe aware of a way to make it compatible with member functions/functors? I'm thinking of type erasure through template, ie. a virtual function call (this is what `std::function` does I believe)..

Comment: @Nikos Just bind a lambda to it and let the lambda capture do the hard work

Comment: Yes indeed that works. Although not as a universal solution as `std::function`.

Comment: @Nikos You shouldn't use `std::function` as a replacement for generic callables anyway

Answer (score 2):

`R(*pf)(void*, Args...)` is a function pointer (regular one, not pointer-to-member) to a function that returns `R` and has `(void*, Args...)` parameters, where `Args...` is a list of types (an expanded template parameter pack).

> Maybe this `void*` represents `this*` and its another way to define a member pointer variable

Nah, there is no such feature in C++.

If you look at [the code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39087141/alternative-to-stdfunction-for-passing-function-as-argument-callbacks-etc/39087660#39087660), the only things assigned to this pointer are lambdas, like this one:

```
pf = [](void* ptr, Args... args)->R{
  return blah;
};
```

I'm not sure why you expected pointers-to-members to be involved.