# invalid cast from type âvoid*â to class member_function pointer

Tags: c++, reinterpret-cast

```
typedef A::T*(Processor::*myMethodType)(const FDS::T*);

myMethodType temp = NULL;

temp = reinterpret_cast<myMethodType> (myInterface.findMap(moname)))
```

Note: 
Processor is a class which instantiated Template class .
myMethodType is the member-pointer-func pointer .

Note : findMap is returning a void* as seen below and myinterface is a map of

```
template <class Implementor>

void* Interface<Implementor>::findMap(std::string &name){
    if (myInterface.find(moname) != myInterface.end()) {
        return myInterface.find(moname)->second;
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

========================================================

Getting below error  -

```
error: invalid cast from type âvoid*â to type âProcessor::myMethodType {aka T* (Processor::*)(const T*)}â
      if((temp = reinterpret_cast<myMethodType> (myInterface.findMap(moname))) != NULL)
```

Question  - why am I getting this error, though I am casting it to member_class_pointer?
why Invalid conversion?

Tried till now  :

Tried below approach from  --- 
 `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307278/casting-between-void-and-a-pointer-to-member-function`

```
void myclass::static_fun(myclass *instance, int arg)
{
   instance->nonstatic_fun(arg);
}
```

but no luck so far !!

Comment: `is returning a void*` - right, so it's not returning `myMethodType` nor `FDS::T*(Processor::*myMethodType)(const FDS::T*);`, it's returning `void*`. What is your question?

Comment: why does it say invalid conversion?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1307278/17034

Comment: You first should think of C++ programming in general. Having a void* in your code should always alarm you!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cast between function pointers and object pointers (such as `void*`). If you want a map with multiple function pointer types, you can convert them to some more function pointer type, such as `void*(*)()`. Function pointers must be converted back to the original type before calling them.

If you don't need multiple function pointer types, you can use a map of `myMethodType`.

Comment: you mean to say - I should have use a map of  `void*(*)()` instead of `void *` ?

Comment: Why not use a map of `myMethodType` ?

Comment: as myMethodType is a member-function -pointer to a template class , which is instantiated by different `types` .

Answer (score 0):

A regular pointer is different from pointer-to-member. Since `reinterpret_cast` conversion (see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast)
a pointer can be converted to another pointer or to an integral type, but not to pointer-to-member

Comment: but void pointer does not know which type it is pointing to ? so it can not be considered as a regular pointer, it may be a pointer to member, please correct me.

Comment: Pointer and pointer-on-member it's just different types. You can not cast it to each other. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer `Typically, mentions of "pointers" without elaboration do not include pointers to (non-static) members.`

Comment: Probably you should change return type on `void*` for `myMethodType` and return `myMethodType` from `find`

Comment: We cant change to myMethodType , as this is a template class

Comment: Do you implement this class? If so, you can freely change the return type of methods to `void*`