# Is it possible to obtain a pointer to the definition of a pure virtual function?

Tags: c++, virtual-functions, pointer-to-member, pure-virtual

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calling base class definition of virtual member function with function pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207106/calling-base-class-definition-of-virtual-member-function-with-function-pointer)

Given the following hierarchy:

```
struct Base
{
  virtual void f() = 0;
};

void Base::f()
{
  cout << "Base::f\n";
}

struct Derived : Base
{
  void f()
  {
    cout << "Derived::f\n";
  }
};
```

We can force a call to `Base::f` like so:

```
Derived d;

d.Base::f();
```

or:

```
Base * b = &d;

b->Base::f();
```

No surprises there.  But is it possible to obtain a member function pointer through which `Base::f` can be called?

```
void (Base::*bf)() = &Base::f;

for_each( b, b+1, mem_fn( bf ) ); // calls Derived::f
```

(For the record, I don't actually have a need to do this.  I'm just curious.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As James McNellis commented the short answer is just "no".

The longer answer is, "if you're willing to accept some *formal* UB, then":

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>    // for_each
#include <functional>      // mem_fn
using namespace std;

struct Base
{
  virtual void f() = 0;
};

void Base::f()
{
  cout << "Base::f\n";
}

struct Derived : Base
{
  void f()
  {
    cout << "Derived::f\n";
  }
};

int main()
{
    struct DirtyHack: Base
    {
        void baseF() { Base::f(); }
    };

    Derived d;
    void (Base::*bf)() = static_cast< void(Base::*)() >( &DirtyHack::baseF );
    Base* b = &d;

    (b->*bf)();
    for_each( b, b+1, mem_fn( bf ) ); // calls Base::f
}
```

I wouldn't do this, but then, I would generally not use raw member function pointers anyway (bound ones are a different matter, e.g. for GUI events).

Note that if you control the `Base` class, then you can just factor out the functionality that you want to be accessible non-overridden.

Comment: +1 for providing new material for my nightmares.